# Issue While Prototyping In javascript

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

```
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    return Greeter;
})();

var Greeting = (function(){
    Greeting.prototype = new Greeter();        
    Greeting.prototype.constructor = Greeter;
    function Greeting(greeting){
    } 
    return Greeting;
})();



var greeting = new Greeting("World");
alert(greeting.greet());
```

I'm trying to manipulate inheritance using javascript prototyping. I have a class structure like above. But when I call the greet method it display some thing like the below image shows. Can anybody guid me on this ?

[image]

Comment: This is so complicated it's hard to get you intent. Whatever it is, there's a simpler way to achieve it.

Comment: His intent seems to be to inherit the `Greeter` object, and override the constructor

Comment: Seemingly you already have a jsFiddle. You could have posted the link at the same time, so it would be easier for us to play with the code :).

Comment: Sorry about that next time if I have a question I will be doing it. @dystroy is it a bad way of prototyping in javascript ? It would be a great support if you could explain me further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never invoking the "constructor" function `Greeter` when you are creating the `Greeting` object. So the `this.greeting = message;` line never runs, that is why it is `undefined`.

You have to either insert that line manually:

```
function Greeting(greeting){
    this.greeting = greeting;
}
```

or invoke the parent constructor:

```
function Greeting(greeting){
    Greeter.call(this, greeting);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and I got the issue any ways I really appreciate your time on this.

Comment: but I have put a log inside 
Greeter and it does getting logged in console but with an undefined greeting.

Comment: @CodeDecode Yes, because of this line: `Greeting.prototype = new Greeter();`. To do your inheritance stuff, you are calling the `Greeter` function, with no parameters - hence the `undefined`.

Comment: Have one more question is this the proper way of doing inheritance in javascript? I believe I'm not bothering you. Because I got confused with one of the comment posted by @crush

Comment: @CodeDecode It's hard to tell what is the *proper* way of doing inheritance in Javascript. Some people don't prefer this classical way and there are many different methods. I normally like using an `Object.create()`-based model, not constructors functions and function prototype.

Comment: @CodeDecode The second option from above is what you want. I don't know how I confused you. You did the first option above, which is NOT what you wanted to accomplish.

Comment: @crush Thank you, Yeah u put up a valid point. Sorry about my mistake

Comment: Actually the line *does* run, with `greeting` being `undefined`: `Greeting.prototype = new Greeter();` (just what [one should not do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here))

Answer (score 2):

In your "greet" method of your Greeter you call this.greeting. However, in your Greeting object you haven't defined a "greeting" method...

Comment: Thank you, and I got the issue any ways I really appreciate your time on this.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `greeting.greet()`, `this.greeting` is `undefined`, thus the problem.

**Explanation:**

Try this code:

```
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    return Greeter;
})();
console.log('Log 1: ' + Greeter);

var Greeting = (function(){
    console.log('Log 2: ' + Greeting);
    Greeting.prototype = new Greeter();        
    console.log('Log 3: ' + Greeting);
    Greeting.prototype.constructor = Greeter;
    console.log('Log 4: ' + Greeting);
    function Greeting(greeting){
    } 
    console.log('Log 5: ' + Greeting);
    return Greeting;
})();

console.log('Log 6: '+Greeting);


var greeting = new Greeting("World");
alert(greeting.greet());
```

You will see that `Greeting` is just an empty function, but with `Greeter` as the prototype.  So, `new Greeting('World')` creates the following function:

```
function Greeting(greeting){
}
```

with a prototype containing `greeting` (undefined), `constructor` (a function), and `greet` (a function).  `Greeting.prototype.greet`, in turn, has this definition:

```
Greeting.prototype.greet = function () {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
};
```

But `this.greeting` is undefined in this context, because `this` refers to `Greeting.prototype.greet`, not `Greeter`. Thus, these lines:

```
var greeting = new Greeting("World");
alert(greeting.greet());
```

fail, because `greeting.greet()` returns `Hello,` concatenated with an undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

You call `greet` method on `Greeting` context which don't have `greeting` property.

And there is no reason to wrap code in IIEF in your case, because there is no private vars, so (it works):

```
var Greeter = function (message) {
    this.greeting = message;
};

Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
};

var Greeting = function (greeting){
    Greeter.call(this, greeting)
} 

Greeting.prototype = new Greeter();        

var greeting = new Greeting("World");
alert(greeting.greet());
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `Greeting` class like this:

```
var Greeting = (function(){
    function Greeting(greeting){
        Greeter.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Greeting.prototype = new Greeter();        
    Greeting.prototype.constructor = Greeter;
    Greeting.superClass = Greeter;

    return Greeting;
})();
```

or if you want to create a general solution for all of your inheritance model, do this:

```
var Greeting = (function(){
    var Greeting = function $SubClass(greeting){
        $SubClass.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Greeting.prototype = new Greeter();        
    Greeting.prototype.constructor = Greeter;

    return Greeting;
})();
```

The important point in this part:

```
var Greeting = function $SubClass(greeting){};
```

is when you directly assign the function to a variable, you would have access to your function based on its label ($SubClass) only in the function context.

Comment: Be careful with `arguments.callee`, ECMAScript 5 forbids its use in strict mode.